# "allowDefinition='MachineToApplication'" error occurs when setting a host name for an ASP.NET MVC 4.0 site in IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5

I'm trying to configure a host header for an ASP.NET MVC 4.0 site in IIS. If I don't set the host name in the http binding I can browse to the site without issue. However, once I set the host name I get the following error:

> ### Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Configuration Error 
>   Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond the application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.
>
> Source Error:
>
> ```
> Line 53:     <compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
> Line 54:     <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
> Line 55:     <authentication mode="Windows" />
> Line 56:     <authorization>
> Line 57:       <deny users="?" />
> ```
>
> Source File: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\oms\web.config    Line: 55
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929

I researched this issue and saw that most who encountered it usually had a web.config file in a sub-directory that included authentication settings. I tried performing Clean operations in Debug and Release modes, deleting the obj folder, and ensuring I had no backup folders. The only other web.config I have is the one in my Views folder. I haven't added anything to that file, but it's possible there could be something in it causing a problem. Here's my Views web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
    </httpHandlers>

    <!--
        Enabling request validation in view pages would cause validation to occur
        after the input has already been processed by the controller. By default
        MVC performs request validation before a controller processes the input.
        To change this behavior apply the ValidateInputAttribute to a
        controller or action.
    -->
    <pages
        validateRequest="false"
        pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <controls>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I'm unsure about it being a configuration issue since the site works when I don't set the host name.

How do I correctly host an ASP.NET MVC 4.0 site with a host header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to publish my site with a host header without getting this error message when publishing to a dedicated site in IIS. However, I was able to get it working by publishing to the Default Web Site via Web Deploy in Visual Studio 2012.

I used the following in the web deploy connection configuration:

**Service URL**: http://*ServerName*

**Site name**: Default Web Site/*SiteName*

**Destination URL**: www.*SiteName*.com

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337(v=vs.110).aspx

The site can now be accessed by browsing to http://*ServerName*/*SiteName*.